# Using Entity Framework Code First CTP4 how to map an entity to multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ctp4

Using CTP4 and Code First, is it possible to map a single entity to two tables (using a 1-1 relationship between the two tables)?

If so, how?

MSDN: "How to: Define a Model with a Single Entity Mapped to Two Tables" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896233.aspx

Related: [Mapping data from 2 tables to 1 entity - Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880237/mapping-data-from-2-tables-to-1-entity-entity-framework-4)