# How to display in DataGridView data from foreign key table using a model-first entity data model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, datagridview, foreign-key-relationship

I generated a Visual Studio 2010 entity data model [derived from a (mysql) database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html).

```
Users
- UserID
- Username
- UserGroupID

Groups
- GroupID
- GroupName
```

The edmx diagram properly shows the relationship between the two tables (one to many). If I drag & drop the users datasource onto a form, a datagridview shows up, and it is correctly populated with the username, etc when I run the application. However, it shows column with the (correct) UserGroupID, instead of GroupName. I tried to follow [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/10/15/editing-data-from-two-tables-in-a-single-datagridview.aspx) to get the GroupName to show up, but then I get an error that says

> Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line ###:Must
>   specify mapping for all key properties ...

It seems that this works for one-to-one relationships but [not one-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3881410/68936).

Is it not possible to display the users table with the groupname in a datagridview without adding classes manually, when using a model-first entity data model? If it is indeed not possible, then what is the simplest way to display (and edit) this in datagridview (i.e., possibly not using entity data model?) I thought this would be a rather common scenario, which makes make think that there should be a visual tool-based approach for doing this.

As a tolerable approach, I tried to create a view that displays what I like. I was able to add that view to the model, and add the entity as a data source. However, when dragging that data source onto a form, nothing was displayed in the datagridview. The plot thickens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pff! I gave up on the entity model, and just ended up using good old MySqlAdapter, BindingSource, DataTable.